# What the shorcut code for check single array compare to multidimensional array?

Tags: php

Is there shorcut code from bottom code? the code is work. i think theres a better version of this code. i need to improve cause situation like this mostly in my code. So i creates same many boiler plate.

```
// Array data from post

$post_value = ['action', 'drama', 'comedy'];

// Data from genres table

$genres_table = [
    ["id" => 3, "genre" => "action"],
    ["id" => 2, "genre" => "drama"]
];

// Extract all table genre and save into container 

$container = []; // ['Action', 'Drama']

foreach($genres_table as $genres_tb)
{
    array_push($container, $genres_tb['genre']);    
}

// Check request value is exist inside container

foreach( $post_value as $post_vl)
{
    if(!in_array($post_vl, $container))
    {
        echo "Insert {$post_vl} into database";
    }
}
```

Comment: @Remy: Comments are for comments, if you have an answer then please write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a mixture of [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php#refsect1-function.array-diff-description) and [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php#refsect1-function.array-column-description) to get the missing genres from the `$post_value` array as:

```
$missingGenres = array_diff(
    $post_value,
    array_column($genres_table, 'genre')
);
// For 0 based indexing
// $missingGenres = array_values($missingGenres)
echo '<pre>', print_r($missingGenres, true), '</pre>';
```

In case uniqueness of the posted values is not ensured you could use [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to get the unique values only.

Result:

```
Array
(
    [2] => comedy
)
```